# Injured street dog

Tags: dogs, injury

[image]

We have rescued a two month old puppy after it met a car accident. It is not able to stand as it's hind legs are injured. However, we don't see signs of any severe bleeding. The dog has been resting since then and is eating properly. Has urinated twice in the last 36 hours and has not excreted. Please help.

Comment: can the dog move the hind legs and does it have controll of the bladder when it needs to pee,the best had been to get the dog examined by a vet to see what types of injuries it might have.

Comment: This dog could have severe internal injuries, please get it to the closest Veteranarian's office.

Answer (score 3):

He could have internal injuries more than the external ones. Please keep him hydrated and take him to a vet as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the veterinarian. You need proffessional advice, guidance and treatment.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the dog to a vet as soon as possible as it may be a spinal injury if it’s back legs aren’t working. Spinal injury’s are very serious.